# mysql left join,group by same user and show last result

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, left-join

Basically I want to create a list that shows last message from each user

I've tried this query:

```
SELECT * FROM messages 
LEFT JOIN users ON message_by = user_mail
WHERE message_by = 'currect user' 
OR message_to = 'currect user' 
AND message_time IN (
    SELECT max(message_time) 
    FROM messages 
    GROUP BY message_token
)
GROUP BY message_token 
ORDER BY message_token DESC
```

*message_token is same for messages between two users

the results I got are not showing the last result, where did I go wrong?

Comment: This is something of a faq. Happy New Year

Comment: what faq?happy new here you all

Comment: This question is asked (and, depressingly, answered) every single day in SO - and elsewhere (including the manual)

Comment: Well even google didnt help this time:)
and if theres answer formy question in here that i didnt find could you point me there?

Answer (score 0):

OK, for the first time this year:

```
SELECT
    x.*
FROM
    my_table x
JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        grouping_id
        ,MAX(ordering_id) max_ordering_id
    FROM
        my_table
    GROUP BY
        grouping_id
    ) y
ON
    y.grouping_id = x.grouping_id
AND
    y.max_ordering_id = x.ordering_id;
```

Comment: Well now i confused..select and join from the same table(my_table)?

Comment: Congratulations. You're starting to think like an sqler ;-)